# How to Filter On Load with Microsoft Access Navigation Forms

Tags: forms, vba, ms-access, navigation, subforms

I have a Navigation Form with 3 tabs.  Homes, Customer, Decor.

On the Navigation Form, I have an unbound field LOTNUMSELECT.

On the Subform within the each tab, it has a field called LOT_NUMBER.

Since the master / child relationship doesn't seem to be possible with Navigation forms, I'm looking for the subform to filter on load.

User inputs a lot # in LOTNUMSELECT, then clicks on a tab.  When the tab becomes current, the specific lot # (record) is showing.

I've been doing this from a "control panel" form opening another form with the following code.

```
Dim stDocName As String
Dim stLinkCriteria As String

stDocName = "Decor"

If IsNull(LotNumberSelect.Value) = True Then

MsgBox "Please enter a lot number first."

Else
stLinkCriteria = "[Lot_Number]=" & "'" & Me![LotNumberSelect] & "'"
DoCmd.OpenForm stDocName, , , stLinkCriteria
End If
```

I just don't know how to edit this to work with the Navigation form and subforms.

Answer (score 0):

A navigation control has two parts. Navigation menu and a navigationsubform. Each navigation button (aka tab) will load a target form into the navigationsubform control. Only one form can be loaded into the navigationsubform at a time.
Since the navigationsubform opens your target form, you could use the standard "form_open" method to set your filter or set your recordset accordingly. 
All you have to do, click on the forms open event and within that event you can access the parent controls simply by

```
 dim lotno as long
Lotno = nz(me.Parent!controlname.value,0)
If lotno <> 0 the 
' do your filter or recordset operation
End if
```

You can also use the form_load event. Since you are going to perform the filter after load, it is better to set it on the form_open. This will increase your performance.

Comment: I get your answer, and have added some text to it.  My main question is whether the performance would be better using a tabbed control.  It seems many subforms are linked to a control on the main form and that changing this control needs to effect all the recordsources of the subforms.  Switching tabs from and BACK TO a previous tab without changing the LOTNUMSELECT control will result in more querying if a navigation control is used instead of a tab control.

Comment: Changing the lot number in your main form will require a re-query on navigationsubform.  since your forms will always query upon load you don't need to add extra codes. but this is of course up to you which way you wan to go.

Comment: @HarveyFrench sorry can't see your edits, its been rejected by moderators

Comment: Bloody hell.  I thought they would, they are so sensitive.  I just added a IF statement around it to test for me.parent is nothing  so the form can still be used independently of the main form.  I also mentioned the need for the main form control to have a after update event that would run code  that will filter the sub form. Also, just re-iterated whether a tab control would be better as it loads an keeps data in each tab (if you want it to) and allows the data to be filtered by the main forms control.

Comment: PS.  Rather than using a requery a different filter might be quicker.

Answer (score -1):

PART2

I've had some more thoughts having done some experiments.

I don't think the navigation control is the right control to use for your situation. The navigation control does not seem to have events, and properties that will let you link it to a control on the main form that has the navigation control (which I think is what you are trying to do).

I think you will find it easier to use the "tab control", which is easier to work with in this case.

I think the navigation control is really designed to be a menu that allows you access other forms and reports inside it.

Here's a link to videos about using the tab control:
[video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=n-C639MUtto&index=21&list=PLYMOUCVo86jEgD_6ZgePmPOwGixSPr5FZ)
[Video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bya02IQrqes&list=PLYMOUCVo86jEgD_6ZgePmPOwGixSPr5FZ&index=22)

Here's some links to videos about using the navigation control:
[video 1](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xizDlMUZqw)
[video 2](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=6xizDlMUZqw)
[video 3](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=aNxz9rCgxho&feature=youtu.be)

Here's some notes I made abut the navigation control:

The navigation control has a "navigation subform" which does not have any master/child data links fields.  However, this subform is not a normal subform.

With the navigation control, you have to set the "Navigation target name" property of the navigation button (in the Navigation menu) to be the form you want to appear in the navigationsubform when the button is clicked.

Further more, the button has a property "Navigation Where clause" which I believe be used to set to filter the rows shown WHEN the form is loaded.  There do not appear to be events that will allow you to change this filter when a control is used on the main form.  .

Comment: You completely lost me.  My VB skills are not up to your standards.

Comment: Please see part 2 of my answer

Comment: I've used tab controls before, but the issue is it loads all the data as soon as the form is open.  Since we this database on the road (connected to mysql through MYODBC) it's not beneficial to load all the data at once.  That's why I thought the navigation form was best since it "unloads" data when switching tabs.

Comment: Watch the videos I linked to.  He shows how to only load the form for the tab that is clicked.. Also, note that once data has been loaded for a tab, you might as well keep it, even is another tab is clicked.  This saves getting the data again if the user clicks the first tab again.  You build intelligence using VBA (and muscle in the gym ;-).

Comment: This one is what you need: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=Bya02IQrqes&list=PLYMOUCVo86jEgD_6ZgePmPOwGixSPr5FZ&index=22